# Get whois information using wget

Tags: linux, bash, wget, whois

I get whois information for a bunch of URLs by wget the following address

wget -qO- https://www.whois.com/whois/SampleDomain

At the first phase I wanna not creating a file for each URL, so I use -qO- option.

I want to extract 10 field of every domain (such as, Creation Date, Registrant Name)

My question is: How can I get make a csv file which every row define the domain and each column has the value of the whois information?

Comment: I'd *seriously* recommend a higher-level language for this, such as PHP or Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xmlstarlet, GNU grep and GNU paste. A first step:

```
wget -qO - https://www.whois.com/whois/stackoverflow.com |\
  xmlstarlet format --html --recover 2>/dev/null |\
  xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//pre' |\
  grep -Po '^(Creation Date|Registrant Name): \K.*(?= )' |\
  paste -d , - -
```

Output:

```
2003-12-26T19:18:07Z,Sysadmin Team
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I output the result as the following to a file?
2003-12-26T19:18:07Z,Sysadmin Team

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your update. 

For multi-field like =>

Registrant Name|Registrant Organization|Registrant City|Registrant Country|Registrar IANA ID|Creation Date|Updated Date|Registry Expiry Date

and the following address (https://www.whois.com/whois/academicreviews.us) it does not print the appropriate result!

Comment: There, the lines do not end with a blank character but with a semicolon. Replace `(?= )` with `(?=( |;))`. Use with `paste` for each column one `-`.